# iOS4 ABNewPersonViewController Loses Data Entered when attempting to add a Photo iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have implemented a basic add contact feature to an iOS 4 application.  Following the documentation [from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/400-UI_Controllers/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1), I have created a navigation controller, and set its root view to the ABNewPersonViewController.  I have implemented the delegate as well.  The basic mechanics all work.

The problem I am having is when you add a photo to the new person that is very large (taking a photo or picking one from the library), the ABNewPersonViewController form returns empty when the camera controls are dismissed.  No photo is in the add photo box either.  If I pick a small image (say a screenshot from the iPhone), everything works.  I can see from the debug output: **Received memory warning. Level=1**

Has anyone else run into this? Is there a way to set the photo quality to a lower setting for the ABNewPersonViewController?  Any help appreciated.

```
ABNewPersonViewController *abNewPersonView = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
abNewPersonView.newPersonViewDelegate = self;

UINavigationController *newNavigationController = [UINavigationController alloc];
[newNavigationController initWithRootViewController:abNewPersonView];
[self presentModalViewController:newNavigationController animated:YES];
[abNewPersonView release];
[newNavigationController release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ABNewPersonViewController does not handle memory warnings correctly, [file a bug with apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com/).

Comment: Definitely will get a radar filed with an example project, but that doesn't change the fact I need this feature to work.  At the point where I think I might just write my own controller to handle this.

Comment: I have created a sample project that reproduces the issue (iOS 4.0.2/iPhone 4 Device) and filed a radar with Apple, rdar://8339081